# "TypeError: string argument without an encoding" Flask and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm slowly trying to build a small Rest API using Flask, Marshmallow, SQLAlchemy, and SQLite3.  At some point in the recent future my simple "Get" call for the users table seemed to work, but later I started getting the same argument over and over when trying stuff out.

The error: "TypeError: string argument without an encoding"

This happens when trying localhost:5000/users in my browser.  The exact line is 96 "users = Users.query.all()" and the exact function appears to be the SQLAlchemy.query() according to the stacktrace (I'll post below).

I've tried this simple method different ways via many a tutorial but no avail.  Is it perhaps a Python 2 versus 3 thing?  My small amount of code seems very much exactly how many tutorials are.

The code (the only module):

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_script import Manager, Server
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Schema
from marshmallow import fields


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///../campus.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = 'False'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
manager = Manager(app)

manager.add_command("runserver", Server(
use_debugger=True,
use_reloader=True,
host='0.0.0.0'))


class Users(db.Model):
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    is_admin = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    picture = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username


class Pins(db.Model):
    pin_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    master_comment = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    x_coord = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    y_coord = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    picture = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)
    likes = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    dislikes = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    tags = db.Column(db.String(150))


class Comments(db.Model):
    comment_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    text = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    likes = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    dislikes = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)


class UserSchema(Schema):
    user_id = fields.Int()
    username = fields.Str()
    is_admin = fields.Int()
    password = fields.Int()
    picture = fields.Raw()


class PinsSchema(Schema):
    pin_id = fields.Int()
    parent_id = fields.Int()
    user_id = fields.Int()
    master_comment = fields.Int()
    x_coord = fields.Float()
    y_coord = fields.Float()
    picture = fields.Raw()
    likes = fields.Int()
    dislikes = fields.Int()
    tags = fields.Str()


class CommentsSchema(Schema):
    comment_id = fields.Int()
    parent_id = fields.Int()
    user_id = fields.Int()
    text = fields.Str()
    likes = fields.Int()
    dislikes = fields.Int()


user_schema = UserSchema()
users_schema = UserSchema(many=True)

pin_schema = PinsSchema()
pins_schema = PinsSchema(many=True)

comment_schema = PinsSchema()
comments_schema = PinsSchema(many=True)


@app.route("/users")
def get_users():
    users = Users.query.all()
    return user_schema.jsonify(users)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_all()
    app.run()
```

My traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joshuasonn/PycharmProjects/SIUCampusMapServer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/joshuasonn/PycharmProjects/SIUCampusMapServer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/joshuasonn/PycharmProjects/SIUCampusMapServer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/joshuasonn/PycharmProjects/SIUCampusMapServer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/joshuasonn/PycharmProjects/SIUCampusMapServer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/joshuasonn/PycharmProjects/SIUCampusMapServer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "SIUCampusMapServer.py", line 96, in get_users
    users = Users.query.all()
  File "/home/joshuasonn/PycharmProjects/SIUCampusMapServer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2737, in all
    return list(self)
  File "/home/joshuasonn/PycharmProjects/SIUCampusMapServer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 98, in instances
    util.raise_from_cause(err)
  File "/home/joshuasonn/PycharmProjects/SIUCampusMapServer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/home/joshuasonn/PycharmProjects/SIUCampusMapServer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 187, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/joshuasonn/PycharmProjects/SIUCampusMapServer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 79, in instances
    rows = [proc(row) for row in fetch]
  File "/home/joshuasonn/PycharmProjects/SIUCampusMapServer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 79, in <listcomp>
    rows = [proc(row) for row in fetch]
  File "/home/joshuasonn/PycharmProjects/SIUCampusMapServer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 493, in _instance
    loaded_instance, populate_existing, populators)
  File "/home/joshuasonn/PycharmProjects/SIUCampusMapServer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 593, in _populate_full
    dict_[key] = getter(row)
  File "/home/joshuasonn/PycharmProjects/SIUCampusMapServer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 93, in __getitem__
    return processor(self._row[index])
  File "/home/joshuasonn/PycharmProjects/SIUCampusMapServer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py", line 902, in process
    value = bytes(value)
TypeError: string argument without an encoding
```

Any help would be appreciated!  I've tried rewriting a multitude of ways, and went through quite a lot of stackoverflow posts and github issues trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, you have text data in some row in the *picture* column of the *users* table.

This is possible because unlike many other SQL implementations, [SQLite has dynamic typing](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), compared to static. The type you give to a column defines its [affinity](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#type_affinity), or in other words the recommended type for data stored in that column, but it is a recommendation, not a requirement. In the end you can have text data in an INTEGER column, or such as in your case, data using the TEXT [storage class](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#storage_classes_and_datatypes) in a BLOB column.

An example:

```
In [2]: class User(Base):
   ...:     __tablename__ = 'user'
   ...:     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   ...:     picture = Column(LargeBinary)
   ...:     

In [3]: metadata.create_all()
...
2018-03-09 09:33:37,785 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine 
CREATE TABLE user (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        picture BLOB, 
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
...

In [4]: engine.execute("insert into user (picture) values ('BANG!')")
Out[4]: <sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy at 0x7f7ad8bcc278>
```

Trying to fetch users does not end well:

```
In [5]: session.query(User).all()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-f1275abaf1fd> in <module>()
----> 1 session.query(User).all()

...

~/Work/SO/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py in process(value)
    900             def process(value):
    901                 if value is not None:
--> 902                     value = bytes(value)
    903                 return value
    904             return process

TypeError: string argument without an encoding
```

You'll have to go through your user data and fix manually. Using the [`typeof()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#typeof) function you can find the offending rows:

```
In [9]: session.query(User.id).\
   ...:     filter(func.typeof(User.picture) == 'text').\
   ...:     all()
Out[9]: [(1)]
```

Comment: That was indeed the problem!  I was far from figuring that out, thanks for your help and explanation!